# laravel5 class not found fatal error

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. I got the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class '\App\Providers\Weixin\WeixinApiProvider' not found
```

The program runs fine if I move the class file from `app/Providers/MyProviders` to `app/Providers` and change the namespace from `App\Providers\MyProviders` to `App\Providers`.
But why can't i create the file under `app/Providers/MyProviders/` and set the namespace accordingly? Any help?

this is my class file like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers\Weixin;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WeixinApiProvider extends ServiceProvider{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('WeixinApi',function(){
        return new \App\Services\WeixinApi();
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Try importing the class with a use statement instead of a fully qualified namespace

Comment: Run composer dump-auto load after moving to a new namespace

Comment: \App\Providers\MyProviders\Weixin\WeixinApiProvider in app.php providers when you use  app/Providers/MyProviders

Comment: ‘Run composer dump-auto load after moving to a new namespace’ is correct. many thanks.